# The best way to deploy/redeploy PHP code from github to GCP Compute Engine LAMP Stack [Google Click to Deploy]

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-compute-engine, lamp

overflowers!

Can someone please advice me on the best way to continuously deploy PHP code from github to GCP Compute Engine? Specifically to **GCP Marketplace LAMP Stack**, which is the Google Click to Deploy VM? [Here is the link to the market place](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/click-to-deploy-images/lamp?filter=solution-type:vm&q=lamp%20stack&project=isomr-327422&folder=true&organizationId=true)

Your advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to add details on what is being updated and how updates are installed/configured. To pull code from GitHub to a VM requires a listener installed on the VM to receive the webhook call. This is easy to write. The key is what do to after the Git Pull. That depends on what you have installed on your system. Do a Google search for PHP GitHub WebHook. In other words, you will need to write custom code as each situation is unique.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Very helpful and confirms my theories around the C2D images.

Question. Is it possible to use app.yaml to control C2D VMs?

Answer (score 1):

Click to Deploy (C2D) is an excellent way to test drive solutions but I'm (admittedly somewhat naive but) skeptical that it's a good approach to combine C2D with customization.

That said, the C2D solutions are published and you could, with some work, customize the solution as the basis for your own solution.

In other words, I'd recommend not combining the C2D as-is but to customize the tools that it uses (!) for your needs.

The [README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/tree/master/vm) explains how the LAMP VM is built (Cloud Build, packer, chef).

Without wishing to in any way impugn your approach, please consider alternative ways to deploy PHP to Google Cloud Platform. Running Apache and MySQL on a VM may be entirely appropriate for your needs but you will need to maintain the OS, Apache, MySQL etc.

If you're goal is to deploy a PHP (web) app that needs a MySQL-compliant database and you want to be more "cloud native", you could consider using:

1. App Engine or Cloud Run to host your PHP app (see [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php))
2. Cloud SQL for the database (see [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard))

The above would require more initial work but, if you want more flexibility, resilience and less "chore", I think you'd benefit from the investment.

In addition opening up the app like this would facilitate leveraging Cloud Monitoring, Logging, Debugger etc

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Very helpful and confirms my theories around the C2D images.

Question. Is it possible to use app.yaml to control C2D VMs?

Comment: You're welcome. `app.yaml` is the configuration spec for App Engine apps. If a C2D app were provided as an App Engine app then, yes, you could tailor it and deploy it using `app.yaml` but VMs are Compute Engine resources and these can't be controlled directly by `app.yaml`.

Comment: Makes sense!!! Thank you so much!